# Get the spreadsheet ID from which a web app script was opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I want to create a web app script. I need to add the url generated by the deployment in a cell of another spreadsheet so that it allows me to obtain its ID.

The script only works on the spreadsheet from which I did the deployment. If I execute the URL from the cell of another spreadsheet, it returns the wrong ID (the ID of original spreadsheet).

Is it possible for the app to automatically detect the spreadsheet ID from which cell it was opened? or should it only be done by sending parameters?

I have the following code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var id = getidSheet();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(id);

}

function getidSheet(){
  var idSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  return idSheet;
}
```

Comment: You should send parameters.

Comment: In your situation, is this information useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#event-object-of-web-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web app can't determine the place where the URL is located. If you need to send the ID of the spreadsheet holding the link, you need to add it to the URL. This could be done by adding the spreadsheet id as a value of a [*query string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameter or as the [*URI fragment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) (put it with `#` as prefix)

Let say that the following is the original URL

```
http://www.example.com
```

Using a *URL parameter* (pair of paramenter name and parameter value)

```
https://www.example.com?spreadsheetId=put_here_the_spreadsheet_id
```

Using a *URI fragment*

```
https://www.example.com#put_here_the_spreadsheet_id
```

Then on your web app's doGet function use the event object properties

```
function doGet(e){
  // Log the spredsheetId parameter 
  console.log(e.parameter.spreadsheetId);
  // Log the URL fragment (anything after #)
  console.log(e.queryString.split('#'))[1]));

  retunr HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Hello world!</p>');
}
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web